# Handling concurrency in Entity Framwork on single save for multiple tables & rows

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency

I am implementing concurrency handling in EF6. So far so good, I added RowVersion fields, everything goes fine. Let's say I have a Role table with RoleName and RoleId. If anyone changes the name before I hit SAVE, the app will detect the changes and proceed accordingly. Cool.

Now... let's say I have a RolePrivilege table as well, with the list of Privileges associated to each Role. Both the Role info (name), and the privilege list is sent  to the client side, and then saved all at once upon saving (within a SaveChanges).

Question is... how should we architecture concurrency checking in such scenario?

- Checking RowVersion on Role entity is not enough. There might be changes on RolePrivileges.
- Checking RowVersion on RolePrivileges entities is not enough either. There might be privileges added or deleted, not just updated.

So, it looks like it will require A LOT of custom coding and plumbing...

1) Check if Role has been deleted before saving.
2) Check if Role.RowVersion has been altered.
3) Check if any Privilege has ben removed as compared with the DB version.
4) Check if any Privilege has ben added, as compared with the DB version.
5) Check if any Privilege has a different RowVersion.

Any ideas on how to approach such situacion, as generic and clean as possible? The Role / RolePrivileges is a real case, but simple. We do have screens where we are saving 10+ related entitites on a single transaction, so this might become an issue.

Thanks!